# Imagick долго обрабатывает изображения

Tags: highload, imagick, vps

Доброго времени суток.

Решил перейти на imagick. На локальном компьютере все нормально, обрабатываются картинки достаточно быстро даже если размер >5 mb.

Пришло время все это дело переносить на vps.

Все вроде нормально, но когда я загружаю файлы более 2 мб то изображение обрабатывает примерно полторы минуты! Если же изображения меньше 2 мб то на обработку уходит до 2 секунд.

С чем может быть связанна эта проблема?

Comment: с тем, что оперативной памяти не хватает под все это и приходиться использовать жесткий диск. А он в десятки раз медленнее.

Comment: @M11, вообще @KoVadim правильно написал, но напишите нам характеристики сервера. На 2мб задыхаться - это очень не ок.

Comment: а 2мб картинка ещё ни о чем не говорит. ImageMagick будет картинку распаковывать, а к примеру, gif картинка подобного размера может очень сильно увеличиться в размерах. Я встречал специальным образом сформированные bmp, которые используют [rle](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#RLE). Размеры по максимуму - 64к на 64к. Понятно, что когда это попытаться распаковать, то это как минимум 4 гига. А если не угадать, и попросить ImageMagick преобразовывать в 4байтовый цвет... А размер файла был несколько килобайт (внутри просто команды "поставь пиксель, сдиг вправо 255, вверх 255)

Comment: @KoVadim это мой хрустальный шар

![](http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2014/1/599/w128h1281390846555crystalball128.png)

Я его потер, он сказал, что автор засовывал на обработку вполне банальный и обычный jpg/png. Если это не так, то я, конечно, разобью предателя, но пока он не давал мне повода сомневаться в нём.

Comment: @Etki 

CPU ~0.8
RAM 256MB
SSD 10GB

Ранее когда был GD он такие изображение обрабатывал, примерно 5 секунд но все же. Теперь мне не понятно почему многие говорят что imagick использует ресурсов меньше по сравнению с GD

Comment: @KoVadim после обработки изображения >2mb занимают не более 400кб. Я использовал jpg картинки, а точнее снимки с фотоаппарата.

Comment: а может покажете код, которым кодируете? может там явные косяки?

Comment: @KoVadim http://pastebin.com/6xtSnUSH